# python ast module resource

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

can anyone recommend a resource that shows how the AST module works step-by-step?  particularly the NodeVisitor and NodeTransformer...

Answer (score 2):

Not step-by-step, but good: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/11/28/python-internals-working-with-python-asts/

Answer (score 0):

The Python AST module reference is available [here](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

The entire documentation is available here. Also I recommend watching [Pycon Video](http://pyvideo.org/video/419/pycon-2011--what-would-you-do-with-an-ast#)
As It gives a lot of insight to its working as well as the documentation.